# Run-Time Check Failure #2 Stack around the variable 'maze' were corrupted

Tags: c++

Run-Time Check Failure #2 Stack around the variable 'maze' were corrupted.
Whenever I compile and run my program, I receive this error whenever the program finishes running. I believe the problem is happening in my addPaths function in my implementation. I posted all my code just in case. This program is creating a maze and the addPaths function is "digging" the paths for the user to move through. The path direction is chosen at random and the paths are only drawn at even number spaces on the maze.

HEADER:

```
const int HEIGHT = 3;
const int WIDTH = 5;

class Coordinate
{
public:
    int row, column;
};

class Maze
{
    public:
        Maze();
        ~Maze();
        void buildMaze();
        void displayMaze();
        void addPaths();
        void startGame();
        void movePlayer(int);
        bool solved();
        int getKey();
        void addDestinationToGrid();
    private:
        char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        Coordinate player;

        const static char PLAYER = 'P';
        const static char DESTINATION = 'X';
        const static char START = 'S';
        const static char PATH = ' ';
        const static char WALL = (char)219;
};
```

IMPLEMENTATION:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "maze.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stack>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


Maze::Maze()
{
    buildMaze();
}

Maze::~Maze()
{
    cout << "yay";
}

void Maze::buildMaze()
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= HEIGHT-1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= WIDTH-1; y++)
        {
            grid[x][y] = WALL;
            //SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 4);
        }
    }
}

void Maze::displayMaze()
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= HEIGHT-1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= WIDTH-1; y++)
        {
            cout << grid[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void Maze::startGame()
{
    int input;
    do
    {
            input = getKey();
            movePlayer(input);
    } while (!solved());
}

bool Maze::solved()
{
    return true;
}

void Maze::movePlayer(int direction)
{
    if (direction == VK_UP || direction == VK_DOWN || direction == VK_LEFT || direction == VK_RIGHT)
    {
        COORD newCoord = { player.column + 1, player.row + 1 };
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), newCoord);
        if (grid[player.row][player.column] == START)
        {
            cout << START;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << PATH;
        }

    }
}

int Maze::getKey()
{
    int result = 0;
    while (!solved() && result == 0)
    {
        short MAX_SHORT = 0x7FFF; //111111111111111
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_LEFT;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_UP;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_RIGHT;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_DOWN;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void Maze::addPaths()
{
    Coordinate currentLocation;
    Coordinate startLocation;
    //Coordinate endLocation; //not used yet
    std::stack<Coordinate> myStack;

    currentLocation.row = (((rand() % HEIGHT) / 2) * 2);
    currentLocation.column = (((rand() % WIDTH) / 2) * 2);

    startLocation = currentLocation;
    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column] = START;
    player = currentLocation;
    do 
    {

        bool canMoveUp = !(currentLocation.row == 0 || grid[currentLocation.row - 2][currentLocation.column] != WALL);
        bool canMoveDown = !(currentLocation.row == HEIGHT - 1 || grid[currentLocation.row + 2][currentLocation.column] != WALL);
        bool canMoveLeft = !(currentLocation.column == 0 || grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] != WALL);
        bool canMoveRight = !(currentLocation.column == WIDTH - 1 || grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column + 2] != WALL);

        if (canMoveUp || canMoveDown || canMoveLeft || canMoveRight)
        {
        myStack.push(currentLocation);

            //choose random location to dig
            bool moveFound = false;
            while (moveFound != true)
            {
                int direction = rand() % 4;
                if (direction == 0 && canMoveUp)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row - 2][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row - 1][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.row -= 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 1 && canMoveDown)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row + 2][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row + 1][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.row += 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 2 && canMoveLeft)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 1] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.column -= 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 3 && canMoveRight)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column + 2] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.column += 2;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (!myStack.empty())
        {
            currentLocation = myStack.top();
            myStack.pop();
        }

    }
    while (!myStack.empty());
    addDestinationToGrid();
}

void Maze::addDestinationToGrid()
{
    int randomRow = rand() % HEIGHT;
    int randomColumn = rand() % WIDTH;
    while (grid[randomRow][randomColumn] != PATH)
    {
        randomRow = rand() % HEIGHT;
        randomColumn = rand() % WIDTH;
    }

    grid[randomRow][randomColumn] = DESTINATION;
}
```

MAIN:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "maze.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Maze maze;

    maze.addPaths();
    maze.displayMaze();
    maze.startGame();

    /*if (maze.solved())
    {
        cout << " You Win!";
    }*/
}
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that somewhere you're accessing outside the bounds of the array. A more minimal [MCVE] might make it easier to see where.

Comment: `addPaths` can write outside the bounds of the array. E.g. if `currentLocation.row == 1` then it can write to `grid[currentLocation.row - 2]`, in other words `grid[-1]`. Likewise when `currentLocation.column == WIDTH-2`, it can write to `grid[..][currentLocation.column + 2]`, in other words `grid[..][WIDTH]`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter While that is a problem in typical cases, it isn't here because the `row` and `column` values are always even and `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are odd.  So `currentLocation.row` will never be equal to `, nor can `currentLocation.column` equal `WIDTH - 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.  One is that you are not consistent in the order you access elements of `grid`.  It is declared `grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]` but most (but not all) accesses use a `HEIGHT` based index first.  This isn't causing your problems since `WIDTH` is greater than `HEIGHT` and you stay within the object's memory when doing normal accesses to it.

The problem is this line:

```
grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] = PATH;
```

in the moveRight handler.  The column offset should be `+ 1`, not `- 2`.  The way it is can cause you to write to memory before the first element of `grid`.